# I have a ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom, referenceerror

My code is showing a reference error I don't know why, I'm using node js in webstorm ide.

***My HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
        <h1 id="main-heading"> Movies </h1>
        <div class="movie-list">
            <ul>
                <li class="list-items"> Thor </li>
                <li class="list-items"> Batman </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***My Script***

```
const title = document.getElementById('main-heading');
console.log(title);
```

***Error***

```
const title = document.getElementById('main-heading');
              ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Comment: Where are you running this? `window` and `document` are global objects initialised by browser. So we will need more info about the environment you are running this

Comment: I don't know how to check the environment  I'm just using normal node and an ide webstorm how do I check it?

Answer (score -1):

The type `application/javascript` is obsolete, you can use either
`text/javascript` or `application/x-javascript`.

`application/x-javascript` this is experimental condition better to use the `text/javascript`

It will also work without the type, simply:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: It will work without no type, simply `<script src="script.js"></script>
`

Comment: It's better to edit your answer to add information like this rather than having it in the comments!